# How to remove Customizer's Section and move Control straight to Panel using Child Theme

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

I'm looking for a way to remove the Section `font_selection` and move the Control `body_font_family` straight to the Panel `font_panel` using Child Theme `functions.php`. Below is the sample CODE from parent theme's `customizer.php`:

```
//PANEL
$wp_customize->add_panel( 'font_panel', array(
    'priority'       => 17,
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
    'theme_supports' => '',
    'title'          => __('Fonts', 'theme'),
) );

//SECTION
$wp_customize->add_section(
    'font_selection',
    array(
        'title'     => __('Font selection', 'theme'),
        'priority'  => 10,
        'panel'     => 'font_panel',            
        )
    )
);

//SETTING
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'body_font_family',
    array(
        'sanitize_callback' => 'theme_sanitize_text',
        'default' => $defaults['body_font_family'],
    )
);

//CONTROL
$wp_customize->add_control(
    'body_font_family',
    array(
        'label' => __( 'Body font', 'theme' ),
        'section' => 'font_selection',
        'type' => 'text',
        'priority' => 12
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the parent theme is running the above code at `customize_register` priority 10, you just have to add another `customize_register` action callback that runs afterward, like at 20. However, you cannot move a control to a *panel*. Controls can only reside inside of *sections*. To move a control to another section you can use:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', function ( WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->remove_section( 'font_selection' );
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'some_other_section', array(
        'title' => __( 'Some other section', 'theme' ),
    ) );

    $body_font_family_control = $wp_customize->get_control( 'body_font_family' );
    if ( $body_font_family_control ) {
        $body_font_family_control->section = 'some_other_section';
    }
}, 20 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible to move widgets control to another section ?

Like sidebar_widgets want to move my_section

```
$sidebars_widgets_control = $wp_customize->get_control( 'sidebars_widgets-foot_sidebar' );
    if ( $sidebars_widgets_control ) {
        $sidebars_widgets_control->section = 'my_settings';
    }
}, 20 );
```